# Sorting three numbers in ascending order without using functions

Tags: python

One of my assignments is to write a python program that sorts three numbers in ascending orders without use of any functions like sort or swap.

This is the first thing I came up with:

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
if a < b:
    if b < c:
        print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
    else:
        if a < c:
            print (a, "<", c, "<", b)
        else:
            print (c, "<", a, "<", b)
else:
    if c < b:
        print (c, "<", b, "<", a)
    else:
        if c < a:
            print (b, "<", c, "<", a)
        else:
            print (b, "<", a, "<", c)
```

My teacher said to try and simplify it so I wrote this next (which basically is a roundabout way to use swap):

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
if a > c:
    a = a + c
    c = a - c
    a = a - c  
if a > b:
    a = a + b
    b = a - b
    a = a - b
if b > c:
    b = b + c
    c = b - c
    b = b - c
print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
```

So I guess my question is whether it can be more simplified than this and what that would look like.

Comment: You can swap two numbers with just `a,b = b,a`

Comment: second version is a disaster for readability.  listen to @khelwood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using your approach in the second code, this is the easiest way out:

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))

if a > b:
    a,b = b,a
if a > c:
    a,c = c,a
if b > c:
    b,c = c,b
    
print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you want but you cud use list and sort them like this:

```
for i in range(len(num)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(num)):
        if(num[i] > num[j]):
            temp = num[i]
            num[i] = num[j]
            num[j] = temp
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserving your concept, I would go with something like this (Don't use this version because your swapping concept still needs fixing - see comments below by @thierry-lathuille):

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
if a > b:
    a = a + b
    b = a - b
    a = a - b
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
if b > c:
    b = b + c
    c = b - c
    b = b - c
    if a > b:
        a = a + b
        b = a - b
        a = a - b
print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
```

This way most scenarios will lead to just two if statements instead of three

Combined with the correct `a, b = b, a` swapping notation recommended by @khelwood we get:

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
if b > c:
    b, c = c, b
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
```

This has the advantage of sometimes using only two IF statements instead of three, repairing the faults on the swap process, and having a simplified and more readable code.

Comment: With your first code, with this input: `Enter a: 1.1e308 Enter b: 1e308 Enter c: 0`, I get `nan < nan < inf`. Don't use such bad tricks!

Comment: I was trying to preserve op's concept and focus on showing that moving the last IF inside the second one might improve performance - I agree that swapping numbers with op's method is naive

Comment: You could edit your answer to include a big "Don't do that" with an example of how it could fail" - feel free to use this one - and how your second version is better, that would make your answer much more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple but shorter...

```
a=[int(input("First Number: ")),int(input("Second Number: ")),int(input("Third Number: "))]
for x in range (0,len(a)):
    for i in range (0,(len(a))-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
print ("Little to Bigger Sort:",a)
```

Answer (score 0):

#simple program to sort a list in ascending order

```
name = [1, 2, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0, 8, 2, 9]
len1=len(name)
for i in range(len1): #iteration from 1st value
   for j in range(i+1,len1): #iteration from i+1 
       if  name[i] < name[j]: #this is ascending order (*the < changed to > then ascending order)
           name[i],name[j]=name[j],name[i] #swapping logic in python
print (name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got that assignment once. I can only use if-elif statement. I also ended up using implicit swap, but I swap like this:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

My answer is, it is not possible to further simplify if you need to use only if-elif statement. Here was a prove I send to my teacher proving 3 if is the minimum and no elif is better, if you're interested:

Mathmatically, 3 statements are required in minimum to cover all possible scenarios. There're 6 possible scenarios (a>b, a<b, a>c, a<c, b>c, b<c) and can be condensed into 3 independent conditions (a>b, b>c, a>c) of 2 state (true or false), which can be determined by 3 if statements. However, if we introduce 1 elif statement, to make it equally efficient (so still using 3 statements only), we have to replace one of the if statement with elif (so 2 if + 1 elif instead of 3 if + 1 elif). However, this then have logic gaps because only one of the if and elif will run, but you don't want that because you want both of them to run when both conditions are true, or it cannot cover all possible scenarios. To fix that, you'll have to add new statement(s), then you have more than 3 statements and being inefficient. The new statement(s) must also reuse one of the used condition or its complement, because there're only 3 independent conditions, and all of them are used. The same logic applied when scale up, because for x many input number, there're x many mutually exclusive pairs of independent conditions, and x many if statements are needed, and the same reasoning applied again showing that using elif is not efficient in all cases of this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
a = int(input("Please enter the first value: "))
b = int(input("Please enter the second value: "))
c = int(input("Please enter the third value: "))
lst = []
lst.append(a)
lst.append(b)
lst.append(c)
print(sorted(lst))
```

Comment: I would say that using `sorted` to sort a list would break the "without using functions" requirement of the question.